# Examples of smooth projective varieties with "nice" Picard group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, picard-group, hilbert-function, invertible-sheaves

I am looking for examples of smooth projective varieties $(X,H)$ with $H$ a polarization on $X$, $\dim \mbox{Pic}^0(X)=0$, $\mbox{Pic}(X) \not= \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying the property: for any two line bundles $L_1, L_2$ on $X$, we have $L_1 \cong L_2$ if and only if they have the same Hilbert polynomial.

Comment: What do you assume about polarization?

Comment: @Sasha You can fix a polarization.

Comment: So, the question is about examples of polarized varieties $(X,H)$, right?

Comment: @Sasha I have edited the question

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example. Let $X = P^1 \times Q^3$ and $H = O(1,1)$. The Hilbert polynomial of the line bundle $O(a,b)$ is
$$
P(t) = (t+a+1)(t+b+1)(t+b+2)(t+b+3/2)/3.
$$
It has three integral roots $-a-1$, $-b-1$, $-b-2$, and one non-integral root $-b-3/2$. This allows to reconstruct $b$ from the Hilbert polynomial in a unique way, and after that also reconstruct $a$. Thus, the required property is satisfied.